# Issues with passing pointer arrays and printing them

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having some issues with very simple situations of passing arrays as pointers into functions and returning them. I thought I had pointers figured but I just can't get my head around it.

Here's the code:

```
int* getLottoDraw();
void printArray(int * array);
int find_matches(int * array1, int * array2);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int * lotteryDraw = getLottoDraw();

  printArray(lotteryDraw);

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}

int* getLottoDraw(){
 int draw[6];

 int i;
 srand(time(NULL));

 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     int r = rand() % 49;
     draw[i] = r;
 }
 return draw;
}

void printArray(int *array){
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
         printf("%i ", array[i]);
     }
}
```

One example output is "3 2047 4614546 0 25 45". Not what was hoping for.

Comment: `getLottoDraw()` returns the address of a local variable. use `int* draw = malloc(6 * sizeof(int));` instead of `int draw[6];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a stack address, which end up being destroyed when the function ends.
Stack variables are local variables, their scope is limited to the function they're created.
They're created on the function, and destroyed when the function ends, so if you've try to access this address later you'll get undefined behavior.
You should have a dynamic allocated pointer to be able to access it outside the function, or return by value, copying the content (which can be costly in an array case).

You could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int* getLottoDraw();
void printArray(int * array);
int find_matches(int * array1, int * array2);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int * lotteryDraw = getLottoDraw();

  printArray(lotteryDraw);

  free(lotteryDraw);

  return 0;
}

int* getLottoDraw(){
 int* draw = malloc(sizeof(int)*6);

 int i;
 srand(time(NULL));

 for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     int r = rand() % 49;
     draw[i] = r;
 }
 return draw;
}

void printArray(int *array){
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
         printf("%i ", array[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: @NylePudding You know you can accept an answer? ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Ah, apologies! I tried to accept the answer as soon as you gave it, but of course it doesn't allow you do that too early..